# Can an intelligent item multiclass outside of the Intelligent Item class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, character-creation, multi-classing

Is there any reason an intelligent item taking classes in intelligent item from the book *Complete Eldritch Power* could not also take ranks in other classes? Say fighter or wizard, so that they could have a familiar or take the leadership feat and have a follower to wield them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, intelligent magic items can multiclass if the short variant rule for multiclassing is used. (It's on page 55 of the *Book of Eldritch Might III: The Nexus* and page 69 of *Complete Book of Eldritch Might*.) Those rules also include suggestions for how to handle intelligent magic items casting spells with somatic components.

Answer (score 3):

### There isn't any reason why they cannot...

...so long as they can meet all the prerequisites (if any) and requirements of the class.

Note that levels of fighter will not help your combat potential much, unless the item in question can self wield. Nor will a follower-wielder gain your attack bonus from fighter levels.

And casting spells as a wizard would be rather problematic without the ability to gesture for the somatic components, not to mention handling the spell components.

I would suggest considering psionics for ease of use, otherwise you'll have to be really careful with your level choices.

Note that all magic items are considered constructs, (DMG p.268, paragraph 2 under the Intelligent items section) and thus could always take levels in Construct, gaining feats, skill points, and HD/HP, etc..

Comment: I think that's the second time you've made the suggestion about taking levels in construct. You mean by making a house rule allowing that, right? I mean,—totally correct me if I'm wrong,—but a creature can't normally take levels in its creature type, like a dwarf taking a level in humanoid or whatever, correct?

Comment: With the animate self feat from the eldritch power book, couldn't they also make Somali gestures as they can crudely manipulate objects and are technically mobile?

Comment: @Khaldhool No, it is not sufficient. From the SRD: "Somatic (S)
A somatic component is a **measured and precise movement of the hand**. You must have at least one hand free to provide a somatic component." As you put it, "crudely manipulate" isn't compatible with "measured and precise movement".

Comment: @HeyICanChan Um, no houserule needed that I am aware of. Any character or NPC could take a level in their creature type instead of a class level. Class levels are pretty much just a special type of HD level usually reserved for PCs, NPCs, and certain monsters, at least until Savage Species. After the SS ruleset and the Savage Progressions guidance, *everything* is converted into levels. SS even gives you rules for the conversion of any kind of creature into a level format. Most people won't take straight HD because it's sub-par. Some races specifically mentioning taking HD levels periodically.

Comment: @HeyICanChan And, lots of creatures as presented in the MM(s) are not at the top of their type progression, they have to take HD levels to progress as well.

Comment: But a PC taking a racial Hit Die instead of a class level remains an inference, right? I mean, nothing says, "When a creature earns enough XP to advance a level, a creature can take *either* 1 level in a class  *or* gain 1 racial Hit Die and all the benefits thereof." Does it?

Comment: "A creature’s Hit Dice total is also treated as its level....", "Often, intelligent creatures advance by gaining a level in a character class
instead of just gaining a new Hit Die", "...options for altering standard monsters other than adding character classes or using the monster advancement...", "You must advance a monster by type if it lacks the Intelligence score to gain class levels (minimum 3).", "It gains an ability score increase for every four additional HD; it gains a new feat for every three additional HD; and it gains skill points for each additional HD."

Comment: Quotes taken from MM1 and Savage Species. The former lists two options: class levels and HD advancement; the latter actually lists three possible advancement options when leveling up.

Comment: Ah, here's a couple more: "In general, it is most advantageous for a 1 Hit Die creature with a +0 level adjustment to abandon its monster Hit Die and take class levels." ... "On the other hand, you may wish to keep that one monster Hit Die."

Comment: @HeyICanChan I hope these various references help? Combined, I feel the weight of intent and meaning falls on the side of optionally selecting HD advancement or class advancement, assuming one meets the prerequisites of the latter.

Comment: I've literally *never* considered a PC as having a *choice* to advance its racial Hit Dice instead of taking a class level. That is, a PC takes class levels, and an NPC advances any way the DM wants. Despite the preponderance of evidence you've marshaled, this remains so deeply ingrained in my psyche that I can't help but still disbelieve. That said, enjoy your hard- and well-earned +1 for this comment thread alone. `;-)` (It should probably be moved to chat if only to preserve your work. That, or pose a question on the topic for self-answering.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan As you suggest! https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110818/can-all-creatures-choose-between-advancing-hit-dice-by-type-and-advancing-by-cla/110819#110819 Also, consider that a monstrous PC would by definition have to choose, especially if once it reaches the "standard form", thus finishing the 'required' levels in SS, your particular monstrous PC still has HD it could take to become an advanced version of the race, gain a size category and so forth... thus having to choose between character levels or Hit Dice each level up.