# Is it possible to take levels in monster types?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, class, character-levels

Today I found [this post by /u/pk_powered in the /r/Touhou subreddit about what alignment Touhou characters might be](https://www.reddit.com/r/touhou/comments/3t4qtv/touhou_character_labels_personality_types/), and the [linked spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18l9L-jEret6eKSXMA-51nC9jwPYfAODp3ogKUgXiyZo/edit) also includes a column suggesting classes for the characters.

[A comment by /u/Callinectes](https://www.reddit.com/r/touhou/comments/3t4qtv/touhou_character_labels_personality_types/cx3uulx/) mentions taking levels in fey, outsider, and aberration (not all at the same time):

> Now, let's see. You've given D&D (presumably 3.5e rather than 4e or
>   5e) classes and Pathfinder classes as a category. I can definitely
>   help with that. Going down the line:
>
> [...]
>
> Rumia probably doesn't have class levels, but she'd be a Commoner or
>   just take levels of Outsider (Edit: Or Aberration, depending on how you
>   see Youkai) if she did.
>
> [...]
>
> Letty Whiterock is probably just a Fey.
>
> [...]
>
> Kogasa Tatara is just an Aberration with Aberration levels.

**Are there any alternate rules I'm not aware of that make this possible? Or are they just referring to [monsters as PCs rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/) from the SRD?**

---

If this is possible, it is something I want to do.

We have multiple races based on monsters, and the DM allows 30 RP if we decide to make our own race. I asked my DM if I "can make a race that gets no class only racials as it levels - basically a monster that levels up" and he said "no for now".

I’m also pretty sure "too ridiculous" isn't in my DM's dictionary. At one point we had a player who was a talking Deku Nut, a player who was a magical girl idol bard, and we even have a scenario called "the Powerpuff Girls apocalypse". As long as I can avoid making it OP and justify its existence, he’ll let me get away with it.

Also, on that note, ignore any balancing unless you can somehow balance for a game where you can deal 306 damage in 1 turn and not kill the intended target outright. At level 6, no less.

Comment: Maybe related: [How to handle PC's acquiring templates?](/questions/119572), [How many hit dice do monster player characters have?](/questions/14381)

Comment: Were this for *3.5*, it'd be a duplicate of [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110818/8610) I suspect the rules might be similar, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is in [a comment by /u/Callinectes on the linked post](https://www.reddit.com/r/touhou/comments/3t4qtv/touhou_character_labels_personality_types/cx429uw/?context=1):

> > Fey is a creature type, not a class.
>
> You can take levels in your racial type, if you're a non-humanoid. It's called "[Racial HD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-advancement/#Step_2_Add_Hit_Dice)".

(Note: link added by me for clarity)

So, no you cannot take "levels of" a creature type. However, you can increase your abilities as a creature that you already are. However, this is almost universally weaker than Class Levels. There are very few abilities, if any, that care about how many HD you have as a creature type.